When using `matplotlib.animation` and 'LineCollection`, how to reduce the size of the colors list
I am continuously plotting data using matplotlib.animation with multiple subplots that use a lot of segments. The issue I am running into is that size of the colors list is quite large ['Blue','Blue',... 'green','green','red',..] so the ram being used it quite large. I was thinking of compressing the data, but the issue is that every half second or so, a new data point and segment is added to the plot, therefore I will decompressing the list anyway.
Is there a way to store the strings in a low data format that reduces the computational and storage overhead?

Instead of setting a list of colors, you could set an array of numbers using set_array.  The colors would then be chosen from whatever colormap you choose, using the numbers in the array.

Strange that the color list is problematic when it comes to RAM. I would suspect other parts eating your RAM much faster than color list
